# Automatic sorting flagged items into folder

Tags: ms-office

Is there a way to show all flagged emails in a folder called 'For Followup'? It would basically have to be a folder that has some kind of logic to it that looks for all flagged emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about Apple Mail or Microsoft Outlook?  Both have the option, but they work differently.

In Outlook on my mac, I create a new rule[image: How to enter a rule for flagged items] after I create a new Folder named “For Followup”.

- Select “Flag” for the first condition and “Follow Up” (or nothing) as its defining attribute
- Then Select “Move To” as next item and choose a new folder you named “For Followup”
- Click Save.
- Test out your new rule!

In Apple Mail, Rules don’t include flags.  Also, if you create a new folder in the same way, it won’t automate anything.  Instead:

1. Click on “File” and select “New” and then “New Smart Mailbox”
2. Name it “For Followup”
3. Condition that meets all the following conditions: select “Message has flag”
4. You must choose a flag color to use for the purpose, but it automatically sorts the Followups for you!
   [image: Apple Mail Smart Mailbox]